# AES decrypt file data and write to disk

Tags: c#, encryption, openssl, aes, bouncycastle

I am trying to decrypt file data and write to disk. It's creating the file but it is corrupted. Could you please let me know if there are any suggestions. I am using AES 256 algorithm.

```
  column_data =  string_data //base64 encoded string
  byte[] data_bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(column_data);
  string decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data_bytes);

  bytes[] decrypted = DecryptAESText(decodedString, secret, iv);

  File.WriteAllBytes(@".\file.gif", decrypted );


    // DecryptAESText returns the decrypted text, receives text in Base64
    public static byte[] DecryptAESText(string cipheredText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        IBufferedCipher cipher = InitAESCipher(false, Key, IV);
        string plainText = string.Empty;
        byte[] plainBytes = null;
        try
        {
            byte[] cipheredBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipheredText);
            plainBytes = new byte[cipher.GetOutputSize(cipheredBytes.Length)];
            plainBytes = cipher.DoFinal(cipheredBytes);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(e.ToString() + "Issue in DecryptAESText column Name:");
        }
        return plainBytes;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by corrupted? The file is corrupted or the decrypted data does not make sense?

Comment: Maybe this helps you https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14892/review-of-simplified-secure-encryption-of-a-string

Comment: I am not sure. It looks like decrypted data doesn't make sense.

Comment: It starts badly: `UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(...))` does not make a whole lot of sense. And then, inside the DecryptAESText you call FromBase64String() again. Are you very sure it was Base64 emcoded twice? Because that's very unlikely.

Comment: It was encoded once. I tried removing UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(...)) line, but still I have the same issue.

Comment: Do yo have access to the encrypting code? Because you'll need to verify each step of the transport, and also the Key and IV.

Comment: How would I verify the transport? I do have access to the code.

Comment: Well, `cipheredBytes`, Key and IV should match their counterparts during encryption. Check the Lengths and at least sample the first and last bytes. A log file is helpful.